# How can i merge two signals in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I am really new in c# and would like to merge 3 different signals in one Array. It is really easy to merge vectors in matlab but I have to create this Array in c#.
The following code was created in matlab

```
PN=[pn_1;pn_2;pn_3];
```

I created Array in c# and tried to merge them this created Array but it does not work and I received this error messaga

> "RealNumberSignal' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and no extension method 'Union' accepting a first argument of type 'RealNumberSignal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

What i did is :

```
var arr = PN_Zahl_Phase1.Union(PN_Zahl_Phase2).ToArray();
```

Note i would like to merge three vectors

Thanx a lot

Comment: Please show the declaration of `PN_Zahl_Phase1` and definition of `RealNumberSignal`

Comment: The problem is probably that `PN_Zahl_Phase1` is a multi dimensional array. The LINQ extension methods (`Union(...), Select(...)`) etc only works for single dimension arrays. You'll need to solve it either with by using single dimension arrays or not use `Union(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (not necessarily the fastest) way to achieve what you want may be the extension method `Enumerable.Concat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)`. This will take any two `IEnumerable<T>` collections - which is implemented by plain arrays, too (`double[] : IEnumerable<double>`) - and concatenates them.

```
double[] phase1, phase2, phase3;
// arrays are allocated and filled
double[] result = phase1.Concat(phase2).Concat(phase3).ToArray();
```

If you have the arrays `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, `{ 4, 5, 6 }` and `{ 7 }` result will be `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }`.

**Please note**: `Concat` does not *alter* the collection, but creates a new one. Hence the result of the first `Concat` will be used as a starting point for the second one. At the end we are calling `ToArray`, since `Concat` returns an `IEnumerable<double>`.

I hope that I got your requirements right (I'm not that into MATLAB any more). If you were looking to create a `Nx3` 2-dimensional array, I will have to disappoint you. C# does not aim to be a maths DSL, but rather a general purpose programming language and hence lacks fancy matrix methods. Baking a 2-dimensional array from multiple 1-dimensional arrays is a lot more work in C# than it is in MATLAB.

Comment: 'RealNumberSignal' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'RealNumberSignal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
I recieved this error message. My Array is just one dimensional

Comment: I have been generally talking about merging arrays. `RealNumberSignal` is not a class known to me and I assumed that it's a class you have written by yourself. Is it a third party class?